# How Do I Make a Image Download that repeats the download For A Set Amount of Times

Tags: html, download

This is my current code. But The Downloading will not work. I need a hundred downloads to happen when Someone clicks a button. Please help

```
  <body id="body">
    
    <script>
    
    var i = 0;
      
      while i < 100{
      
      document.getElementById('download');
      i--;
        
      }
      
    </script>
    
    <center>
    
    <a href = "EXAMPLE.PNG" download = "EXAMPLE.PNG" id = "download"></a>
    
    </center>
    
  </body>
```

Comment: Not gonna happen. This would be abused. One click, one download. No clicks, no downloads; doing things like this without user interaction is largely not possible in modern browsers.

Comment: `document.getElementById('download');` - What exactly do you expect this line of code to *do* and why?  (Not to mention the infinite loop you've created...)  Did you mean to *do something* with that element?  Invoke a `click` event on it, for example?  (Though this probably isn't a good idea either, nor is it particularly clear what you're actually trying to accomplish or why.)

Answer (score 0):

Browsers typically restrict excessive or repeated downloads to prevent potentially harmful behavior. Initiating 100 downloads at once is very likely to be flagged as unusual or potentially dangerous behavior. Even if the browser doesn't outright block the downloads, it may prompt the user for confirmation for each download.

However, if you want to go ahead and do this anyways, below is a revised version of your code:

```
<body id="body">
  <center>
    <!-- user's button to trigger downloads -->
    <button id="downloadButton">Download</button>

    <!-- hidden link for downloading the file -->
    <a href="EXAMPLE.PNG" download="EXAMPLE.PNG" id="download" style="display: none;"></a>
  </center>

  <script>
    // get the button and link
    var downloadButton = document.getElementById('downloadButton');
    var downloadLink = document.getElementById('download');

    // add click event listener to the button
    downloadButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      // loop 100 times to trigger the download
      for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        downloadLink.click();
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

**Note:** [There are better ways to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery), but building off your current code, these would be the corrections.